# Is it possible to automate the eSigning process in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, signing

I have the following three servers:

1. Jenkin Server (Linux).
2. Token Machine Server (Windows).
3. Build Machine Server (Windows).

The task is to trigger the build in the build server through Jenkins. And the generated jar should be signed using the token machine.

Is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: Please add some code what you have tried so far, where you are stuck ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.